# UIviewController with identifier

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working in a small app that connects with  sqlite. It brings the data to list in the tableview without any problems, but when click in the cell to display details, it does not work and  errors are not found.

this is the code how I call the UIviewController with identifier:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    Report11ViewController *destino = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"visualizacion"];
    Vehiculo *tmp = [vehiculos objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   destino.vehiculo = tmp;

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:destino animated:YES];
}
```

I put in Attributes inspector identifier: visualizacion
Please any help will be appreciate. thanks

Comment: Tell us a little more. Is "destino" getting set? Was this table view controller instantiated from the same storyboard that contains "visualization"?

Comment: 1. Check if destino is nil.
2. Check if navigationController is nil.
3. Why don't you use segue?

Comment: thanks Sviatoslav Yakymiv . I tested again and the navigation controller is nil. How can i fix that?. Btw i change to segue but still the same problem. Thanks in advanced four your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this code:

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"get it some name"]) {
    UITableViewCell*cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender;
    NSIndexPath*ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    Vehiculo*tmp = [vehiculous objectAtIndex:ip.row];

    Report11ViewController *destino = (Report11ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    destino.vehiculo = tmp;
  }
}
```

But be sure that your segue to Report11ViewController have identifier same as in that code (get it some name)

Comment: This helped me a lot, but my error was another thing, i did not set navigation controller as is initial view controller. Hope it help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need setup "StoryboardID" in Identity inspector, not Attributes.
And Report11ViewController VC must be in the same storyboard as you table view.